# How to use GDAL RasterizeLayer (python binding) -where flag

Tags: python, gdal, rasterization

I am trying to use GDAL RasterizeLayer python binding, but I can not find a way to use the `-where` flag.

The 'pure' GDAL command I am trying to run is:
`gdal_rasterize -b 1 -burn 0.00001 -where 'DN=255' -l pilot_1class.lazground_poly pilot_1class.lazground_poly.shp testdiff_again.tif`

I am trying to use this in python:
`gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], layerPoly, None, None, burn_values=[0.0001], options = ['ALL_TOUCHED'])`

Comment: I'm assuming the target_ds exists and has the correct GeoTransform. I've not used RasterizeLayer in python but have done in C++ (which python derives from), in that API the where clause is on the layer (like Esri). Testing this in python I have confirmed that using layerPoly.SetAttributeFilter('DN=255') will reduce the layer to only those features that satisfy the query which in turn should be the only features rasterized.